# Python progress bar selecting limitation

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, progress-bar

I'm using Tkinter with a progress bar.

I've got the code below with the **"callback" function** that adding 50% to my progress bar.
I would like to **limit the function to work only once for each OptionMenu selection**.

Currently, I can click twice on the first OptionMenu and get to 100% in the progress bar.
Does anyone know what I should change in the "callback" function in order to make it work only once for each OptionMenu? No matter how many times the user has clicked to change its selected value.

[image]

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar

root = Tk()
root.title('Input window V1')
root.geometry('600x400')
root.resizable(False, False)

frame = Frame(root, width=600, height=400)
frame.configure(background="gray28")
frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

progress = Progressbar(root, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=300, mode='determinate')
progress.place(x=150, y=15)

Budget = {'Flexible', 'Variable', 'Fixed'}
Commitment = {'High', 'Medium', 'Low'}

def callback(*args):
    progress["value"] += 50

bottom_header = Label(root, bg="gray28", fg="white", pady=3,
                  font=("Helvetica", 20, 'underline'), text='Please fill the following attributes:')
bottom_header.place(x=110, y=100)

lbl1 = Label(root, bg="gray28", text='Budget:', fg="cyan2", font=("Helvetica", 14))
lbl1.place(x=120, y=200)

lbl2 = Label(root, bg="gray28", text='Commitment:', fg="cyan2", font=("Helvetica", 14))
lbl2.place(x=120, y=240)

var1 = StringVar(root)
pl1 = OptionMenu(root, var1, *Budget)
pl1.config(width=20, bg="GREEN", fg="white")
pl1.place(x=250, y=200)

var1.trace("w", callback)

var2 = StringVar(root)
pl2 = OptionMenu(root, var2, *Commitment)
pl2.config(width=20, bg="GREEN", fg="white")
pl2.place(x=250, y=240)

var2.trace("w", callback)

global var_dict

var_dict = dict(Budget=var1,
                Commitment=var2)

button1 = Button(root, text="Test")
button1.config(width=25, bg="white")
button1.place(x=220, y=320)

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a variable as a flag that tells your program if the program already added 50% to the progress bar

Comment: What do you mean? Adding boolean to the "callback" function? and how I would make it work (Adding percentage) only if the user really selected a value? and if the user regrets and wants to change the selected value it won't add more percentage?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. It looks like you already know how to set the percentage to any value you want.

Comment: I think the hard part and the confusion is in how to let the callback function know which StringVar called it.
One possibility is to make 2 callback functions, 1 for each variable, another is to use lambda expressions as in my answer underneath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar

def callback(*args):
    user_input = (var_1.get(), var_2.get()) # Here you can add even more variables
    value = 100 - 100/len(user_input)*(user_input.count("")+user_input.count("Select option"))
    progress.config(value=value)

root = Tk()

progress = Progressbar(root, orient="horizontal", length=300)
progress.pack()

var_1 = StringVar(root)
var_1.trace("w", callback)

optionmenu_1 = OptionMenu(root, var_1, "Select option", "Option 1", "Option 2")
optionmenu_1.pack()

var_2 = StringVar(root)
var_2.trace("w", callback)

optionmenu_2 = OptionMenu(root, var_2, "Select option", "Option 1", "Option 2")
optionmenu_2.pack()

# You can remove these if you don't like them:
var_1.set("Select option")
var_2.set("Select option")

root.mainloop()
```

It counts the number of empty `OptionMenu`s and setts the progress bar to the correct percentage.

Comment: it workes for me. I just add more vars (I've got 14) and changed the percentage. Thanks for the great function solution

Comment: @User1 I changed the `value = ...` line so you don't have to work out the percentages by hand :D. The only thing you will need to change is the `user_input = (...)` for your 14 options

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of which of the two you have already accounted for, and update only if there was not yet 50% added for this part.
The callback function is changed (and is understandable) and the passing of the callback is changed to a lambda function (which can be confusing if you never used them).

this works for me:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar

root = Tk()
root.title('Input window V1')
root.geometry('600x400')
root.resizable(False, False)

frame = Frame(root, width=600, height=400)
frame.configure(background="gray28")
frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

progress = Progressbar(root, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=300, mode='determinate')
progress.place(x=150, y=15)

Budget = {'Flexible', 'Variable', 'Fixed'}
Commitment = {'High', 'Medium', 'Low'}

budgetset = False
commitmentset = False
def callback(nb):
    global budgetset, commitmentset
    if nb == 0 and not budgetset:
        budgetset = True
        progress["value"] += 50
    if nb == 1 and not commitmentset:
        commitmentset = True
        progress["value"] += 50

bottom_header = Label(root, bg="gray28", fg="white", pady=3,
                  font=("Helvetica", 20, 'underline'), text='Please fill the following attributes:')
bottom_header.place(x=110, y=100)

lbl1 = Label(root, bg="gray28", text='Budget:', fg="cyan2", font=("Helvetica", 14))
lbl1.place(x=120, y=200)

lbl2 = Label(root, bg="gray28", text='Commitment:', fg="cyan2", font=("Helvetica", 14))
lbl2.place(x=120, y=240)

var1 = StringVar(root)
pl1 = OptionMenu(root, var1, *Budget)
pl1.config(width=20, bg="GREEN", fg="white")
pl1.place(x=250, y=200)

var1.trace("w", lambda *_, x=0: callback(x))

var2 = StringVar(root)
pl2 = OptionMenu(root, var2, *Commitment)
pl2.config(width=20, bg="GREEN", fg="white")
pl2.place(x=250, y=240)

var2.trace("w", lambda *_, x=1: callback(x))

global var_dict

var_dict = dict(Budget=var1,
                Commitment=var2)

button1 = Button(root, text="Test")
button1.config(width=25, bg="white")
button1.place(x=220, y=320)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It's much easier to read `var1` and `var2` in `callback` and use that instead of having 2 flags and the `lambda`s :D

Comment: That's a great idea and works fine for me. What if I got up to 10 optionsMenu? I think it should be more generic and make it works without 10 if statments.

Comment: @TheLizzard, that is true, that is an easier solution

Comment: @User1, also true, in that case I would use menusset = [False]*#menus and '''if not menuset[nb]: progress["value"] += 100/#menus; menuset[nb] = True;